# Are there advantages to using private car service over taxis from the airport?

Tags: transportation, taxis, automobiles, airport-transfer

When planning a trip I've seen people say private cars are scams and other people say they can be better than city taxi's because you know how much it will cost ahead of time. Are there any other advantages that a private car may have over a city taxi? Are there any other disadvantages other than the cost? Do city taxis have hidden costs that a traveler should be aware of (such as "running the meter" while waiting for a rider)?

Comment: What's the difference, exactly? A private car service sounds to me like a taxi service where you don't share with someone, which should be your prerogative anyways.

Comment: The difference is that private car service is run by a company, where as the taxi is run by the city / government. Usually you wouldn't share a taxi with someone unless they were going to the same hotel as you.

Comment: Ah, I'm not used to the idea of taxis being run by the government.

Comment: You should be aware the cars not from companies - just some person wanted to make money.

Comment: where? I would think that the answer to this question varies depending on country and city.

Comment: Back in the day, I was stationed at an Army base just West of Boston. There were taxi's in Boston, but taking one to the Army base would have been ... oh $50-60. There were limos, actually private cars, who did the trip for a flat $40, which if you could split with other people meant a nice cheap ride (they were not per person back then.)

Answer (score 6):

When using a regular taxi make sure it's with a reputable company or you agree upon the rate upfront. In a lot of countries taxis will take every opportunity to rip off tourists.

You'll generally not have this problem with private car services.

Private car services are also generally more comfortable and easier to have little stops or detours along the way.

Answer (score 6):

This completely depends on the city and situation. I've only used a private car service once, in Lima, Peru, as the taxi drivers are notorious for ripoffs and theft. When I arrived at the hostel I was staying at, there were two people staying there who had all of their belongings stolen by their taxi driver at knifepoint. An Australian tourist was also recently shot by her taxi driver in Lima after refusing to hand over her belongings.

In retrospect it seems like that was $20USD well spent, but I wouldn't bother paying it in places that didn't have a reputation.

Comment: Good point about security. In fact Lima is one of the cities where I've used a private taxis.

Answer (score 4):

Taxis aren't run by the government everywhere. For example, here in the Czech Republic the government recognizes two types: taxi and yellow taxi (the main difference being that yellow ones can use taxi stands and special lanes) - but both are private cars by your definition.

It is not possible to answer the question in a way that applies globally because there are different conditions in different countries.

Comment: You can consider the context to be taxi = metered by distance, where private car service = flat rate (typically).

Comment: So here evryone is taxi , flat rate is prohibited by gouvernement ... part about big differences is still applied

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that a normal taxi is always cheaper. The only advantage of a private car service is that the cost is fixed unlike a taxi where the price on the meter (if there is one) can vary depending on the route, how long it takes or how much the driver feels like charging. There is also the possibility of getting ripped off by a taxi driver. Also, the private car services tend to have newer cars and in my experience the drivers can be a little less "crazy". Finally, I've found that in some cities that the only taxis that are possible to call by phone are private taxis and that regular taxis can only be hailed on the street.

Comment: Basically hit all the points in the answer I was typing up: 1) Taxi drivers have the opportunity to inflate your price artificially. 2) As someone who drives through a major city every day, taxi drivers are consistently the worst drivers on the road with little regard for traffic laws or safety.

Comment: It can vary greatly by country though, some countries do not have meters in their taxies and fares are usually negotiated ahead of time.

Comment: A private car (minicab, flat rate) in London will cost half of a black cab (metered) from the airport.

Answer (score 3):

I travelled to Peru with an organised Tour.  We had a guide who accompanied us for the duration of the Tour.  On the final day, when I wanted to get a cab from Lima to the airport, I could have paid an official taxi for about $30.  However, my guide knew someone who can drive us to the airport for about $10 to $15 cheaper.

If someone you trust is providing a private car, you can feel safe to take that instead.  It really depends on your comfort level before you accept a private car from someone.

Answer (score 3):

In some countries, there are regulated and non-regulated 'taxi' services. It so happen that those are generally in countries that are less secure. In those place, absolutely take the regulated ones!